# C++ - Can Class Functions be Declared Outside of Header?

Tags: c++, header-files

I'm fairly new to C++ and trying to write a class that's purpose is to solve a mathematical problem when the class is instantiated with an input. I've broken those calculations up over a couple of sub-functions and so the header/source code looks something like this:

mySolver.h

```
#ifndef __mySolver_h__

class mySolver
{
private:
    double mInput, mOutput; //member variables
    double intermediateCalculation1(double input);
    double intermediateCalculation2(double intermediateValue1);
public:
    mySolver(double input);
};

#endif
```

mySolver.cpp

```
#include "mySolver.h"

mySolver::mySolver(double input)
{
    mInput = input;

    double intermediateValue1 = intermediateCalculation1(mInput);
    double mOutput = intermediateCalculation2(intermediateValue1);

    cout << "Output is: " << mOutput << endl;
 }
double mySolver::intermediateCalculation1(double input)
{
    //do stuff
}

double mySolver::intermediateCaluclation2(double intermediateValue1)
{
    //do stuff while accessing value of member variable mInput
}
```

This works *but* I have to list the methods intermediateCalculation1/2 in the header file despite their being purely implementation details. As a result, if I want to change some of the details of how the calculations are performed (e.g. split things into 3 intermediate calculations rather than 2) I would have to change the header file and re-compile every file that includes mySolver.h which seems to defeat the purpose of separating interface from implementation.

My question is:

1) Is there a simple way to do this without having to include the intermediate functions in the header file?

2) Is there a simple way to do this without having to include the intermediate functions in the header file *that still lets me access member variables in the intermediate functions*?

I've come across some references to the [pImpl technique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) that could be a solution, but for my purposes that seems unnecessarily complicated.

EDIT: Regarding why this is in a class at all, I've simplified my example for clarity but in my actual code I have multiple outputs, some of which are intermediate results I only want to access some of the time (i.e. for error checking), hence my choice of class structure.

Comment: That's what private methods are for: To encapsulate implementation details that aren't for public consumption. For the methods to have access to private class member data, it's easiest to have them be methods in the class.

Comment: You are missing the scope resolution operator mySolver:: when defining intermediateCalculation1 and intermediateCalculation2. So your class functions are never defined.

Comment: your example isnt the best, because there is no reason why those methods should be inside a class in the first place. I mean your class has no state that needs to persist between calls to (public) methods. You have `mInput` and `mOutput`, but they could be simply local variables in  a free function `solve` that calls two or more free functions. tl;dr: you are right, implementation details dont need to be placed in the header

Comment: Well if they are part of the class and only used by the class, then I think it does make sense for them to be member functions. The class provides encapsulation for the functions.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__mySolver_h__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: @jumper0x08 there is nothing to encapsulate here. C++ isnt java. Any function that can be a free function makes a class easier to understand and maintain while it is still considered as part of a class interface. Here the easiest would be to not use a class at all

Comment: @jumper0x08missing scope resolution operator mySolver:: was a typo in the question, my original code has that. Thanks for the catch. Will edit question accordingly.

Comment: @tobi303 I've tried to simplify my original code to get to the crux of my question. In my original code, I have multiple outputs I'd like to return, some of which are true outputs while others are intermediate results I'd like to be able to access for error checking. For this reason, I've made it a class so that I can simply add other getters when needed. If a class is still overkill I'd be interested to hear why.

Comment: not really "overkill", but I dont see the instance here that would need a constructor, destructor and all that stuff that comes with a class. Consider how calling code would look: `auto x = mySolver(3.0);` ? I would find it confusing if I need to create an instance and wouldnt really know what to do with it. I dont know your real code, there defining a class might make sense, but then imho you simplified it too much to demonstrate the crux of the issue. If you worry about debugging and additional print outs I would rather try to group and encapsulate the parameters you are passing around

Comment: @jumper0x08  "The class provides encapsulation for the functions" What does that even mean?  Encapsulation does not mean "member of a class". In fact, adding them to the class when they don't need to be breaks encapsulation. They could live entirely within the .cpp file unexposed to anything outside it. Making them members of the class, even private, exposes them via the header file.

Comment: @RobK I have mentioned if the functions are part of the class and are only used by the class. Of course they shouldn't be added to the class just to encapsulate them in some class. Here, the functions intermediateCalculation s may be better suited to the class depending upon what they do. If there is a class named "LinearEquationSolver", doesn't it make sense for a function SolveLinearEquations() which solves linear equations to be within that class? ( This is assuming, of course having a class LinearEquationSolver actually makes sense in the first place)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Is there a simple way to do this without having to include the intermediate functions in the header file?

Yes. In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46327946/8242698), if you put these into an anonymous (unnamed) namespaces you will really hide those implementation details from any access outside of the translation units. It also helps not to confuse the linker in case of name clashes:

```
namespace { // <<<< unnamed namespace
    double intermediateCalculation1(double input) {
        //do stuff
    }

    double intermediateCaluclation2(double intermediateValue1, double input) {
        // the member variable mInput should be passed as parameter
    }
}

mySolver::mySolver(double input) {
    mInput = input;

    double intermediateValue1 = intermediateCalculation1(mInput);
    mOutput = intermediateCalculation2(intermediateValue1,mInput);

    cout << "Output is: " << mOutput << endl;
}
```

> 2) Is there a simple way to do this without having to include the intermediate functions in the header file that still lets me access member variables in the intermediate functions?

Not really, these would need to be `friend`ed to do so, which requires them to appear at the class declaration.

You still have the option as your code example does now and pass them the necessary parameters, or go with the *pimpl* idiom as you mentioned.  Since *pimpl* only needs a forward declaration, I believe you can do the full declaration and definition in an anonymous namespace as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I really appreciate the example code. Will give your first suggestion a try and mark as accepted answer if it works.

Comment: How does intermediateCalculation2() defined outside the class in the anonymous namespace access the private member mInput that should happen in the function's body according to OP's comments ?

Comment: @Christophe It's not intended to access that private member, but get it passed as parameter.

Comment: @user0042 ok, can you please clarify this assumption by changing the comment "//do stuff while accessing value of member variable mInput"  to reflect this approach ? And SO doesn't let me upvote if there's no edit :-/

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by just defining the function before you use them in the .cpp file.  No need to define them in the header file because there is no need to make them member functions.  These are just free functions.

Also, you probably would want to put them in an anonymous namespace so they are only visible to the existing file.

Comment: OP wants the methods to have access to private member data, so they must be member functions.

Comment: @Gnawme or be declared as friend or OP could realize that there is no need to have those two members if the methods would be implemented as free functions instead of being placed inside a clas

Comment: We've been wasting almost 3 days once, just to find out we had confused the linker by using such construct unprotected by an unnamed namespace. Those few letters additional typing may save you a lot.